# Is there a better way for filter null in a list?

Tags: casting, null, functional-programming, kotlin

I do that for filtering list of null value:

```
val myList: List<Any?> = [...]
myList.filter { it != null }.map { it!! }
myList.get(0).xxx // don't need to write "?."
```

If I don't add the `map`, the list don't become `List<...>`. Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: You can use `mylist.filterNotNull()[0].xxx`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`filterNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html) like so:

```
val onlyPresent = myList.filterNotNull()
```